# Tkinter - how to dynamically create labels named by items in list?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Last time I programmed something when  Basic was new to the world. Now I've dived into python and can't figure out where I'm doing what wrong. The application I am creating loads a large amount of data, processes it and then displays the results. The question is how to ensure that there is exactly one value from the list in each label. the program set in this way will deliver the result shown in the image.

```
import customtkinter

list_names = ("George","Johny","Mike","Anna")

window = customtkinter.CTk()
frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(window)
my_data = customtkinter.StringVar()

frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

for i in range(len(list_names)):
    name = list_names[i]
    my_data.set(name)
    customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame, text=f'{1+i}.Name ').grid(row=i, column=0)
    customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame, textvariable=my_data).grid(row=i, column=1)

# for label in frame.winfo_children(): # this will destroy labels
    # label.destroy()

window.mainloop()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzkNW.jpg)

Comment: You have used the same tkinter variable `my_data` for all the labels in second column, so all those labels will show the last name in `list_names`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the `my_data`  variable inside of the loop and bob's your uncle.

```
import customtkinter

list_names = ("George","Johny","Mike","Anna")

window = customtkinter.CTk()
frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(window)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

for i in range(len(list_names)):
    name = list_names[i]
    my_data = customtkinter.StringVar()
    my_data.set(name)
    customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame, text=f'{1+i}.Name ').grid(row=i, column=0)
    customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame, textvariable=my_data).grid(row=i, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using `textvariable` option in this case is useless because `my_data` only reference the last label after the for loop and so there is no way to reference the other tkinter variable for the other labels.

Comment: @acw1668  I have no idea if the OP added custom functionality to the `StringVar` though since it is imported from an unknown module.